# Array of Workdays

Tags: vba

I am looking for a way to store the last workday of each month between two "Input dates", and I need to store them as Strings in an array. I have tried to use the Worksheet function "Workday", but my input dates are of the format dd-mm-yyy, and I coundn't get it to work..

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify if your question is for VB for Applications (VBA) or VB.NET for the .NET Framework. I assume VBA since you say "Worksheet", but it's possible you might be using VSTO.

Comment: the keyword being **OR**

Comment: You assume correclty :-) I am using VBA, (Excel 2007).

Answer (score 1):

Too bad, i've assumed that your VB.NET tag was the correct one, now it's removed. However, if someone needs something similar in .NET this might be helpful:

```
Dim fromDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1)  ' sample days
Dim toDate = DateTime.Today
Dim startDay = New Date(fromDate.Year, fromDate.Month, 1).AddMonths(1)
Dim endDay = New Date(toDate.Year, toDate.Month, 1).AddMonths(1)
Dim monthsBetween As Int32 = GetMonthsBetween(startDay, endDay)
Dim nonWorkingDays = {DayOfWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Sunday}
Dim workingDatesBetween As New List(Of String)
For month As Int32 = 0 To monthsBetween
    Dim d As DateTime = startDay.AddMonths(month)
    ' look into last months last days, shorter way
    Dim lastWorkingDay As Date = Date.MinValue
    While lastWorkingDay = Date.MinValue
        d = d.AddDays(-1)  ' look backwards into the last month to find the last working-day
        If Not nonWorkingDays.Contains(d.DayOfWeek) Then
            lastWorkingDay = d
            workingDatesBetween.Add(lastWorkingDay.ToString("dd-MM-yyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        End If
    End While
Next
Dim result = workingDatesBetween.ToArray()
```

This method was used to determine the number of months between two dates:

```
Public Shared Function GetMonthsBetween(date1 As DateTime, date2 As DateTime) As Int32
    Dim months = Math.Abs(((date1.Year - date2.Year) * 12) + date1.Month - date2.Month)
    Return months
End Function
```

or as reusable method (although i doubt that someone needs this method often):

```
Public Shared Function GetLastWorkingDatesInMonthBetween(fromDate As Date, toDate As Date) As Date()
    Dim startDay = New Date(fromDate.Year, fromDate.Month, 1).AddMonths(1)
    Dim endDay = New Date(toDate.Year, toDate.Month, 1).AddMonths(1)
    Dim monthsBetween As Int32 = GetMonthsBetween(startDay, endDay)
    Dim nonWorkingDays = {DayOfWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Sunday}
    Dim workingDatesBetween As New List(Of Date)
    For month As Int32 = 0 To monthsBetween
        Dim d As DateTime = startDay.AddMonths(month)
        ' look into last months last days, shorter way
        Dim lastWorkingDay As Date = Date.MinValue
        While lastWorkingDay = Date.MinValue
            d = d.AddDays(-1)  ' look backwards into the last month to find the last working-day
            If Not nonWorkingDays.Contains(d.DayOfWeek) Then
                lastWorkingDay = d
                workingDatesBetween.Add(d)
            End If
        End While
    Next
    Return workingDatesBetween.ToArray()
End Function
```

Now you get the `String()` from the `Date()` via `Array.ConvertAll`:

```
Dim allNonWorkingDates = GetLastWorkingDatesInMonthBetween(DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1), DateTime.Today)
Dim result As String() = Array.ConvertAll(allNonWorkingDates, Function(d) d.ToString("dd-MM-yyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

Result with the sample year above:

```
30-09-2013
31-10-2013
29-11-2013
31-12-2013
31-01-2014
28-02-2014
31-03-2014
30-04-2014
30-05-2014
30-06-2014
31-07-2014
29-08-2014
30-09-2014
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - nice of you to help :-)